# counting number of elements in a list

Tags: python

I have a list

```
my_list = ['TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC', 'TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC', 'AGCTCCCCGTTTTC,AGCTCCCCGTTTTC']
```

I am trying to count the number of times each word occurs in the list. I used the code

```
from collections import Counter
for i in len(my_list):
...     Counter(my_list[i]).most_common()
...
```

I get the error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: remove the `len`

Comment: I suspect you are missing a lot of quotes in that list there.

Comment: Your DNA is a bit short I guess :O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it comes down to what the OP means by *word*.  My interpretation is as follows:

```
for string in my_list:
    print(Counter(string.split(',')).most_common())
```

producing:

```
[('TTATGCTAAGTATC', 8)]
[('TTATGCTAAGTATC', 8)]
[('AGCTCCCCGTTTTC', 2)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your iteration loop is mixing concepts. It should just be:

```
for i in my_list:
  Counter(i).most_common()
```

You don't need to do the indexing.

This gives me:

```
[('T', 48), ('A', 32), ('C', 16), ('G', 16), (',', 7)]
[('T', 48), ('A', 32), ('C', 16), ('G', 16), (',', 7)]
[('C', 12), ('T', 10), ('G', 4), ('A', 2), (',', 1)]
```

Not sure how to interpret that, but perhaps you can. :)

Comment: Your answer is correct, but the OP definitely seems like they need to understand some fundamental concepts of Python before it is of any use to them.

Answer (score 1):

**Instead of using for loop this solution has better time-complexity**

```
from collections import Counter
my_list = ['TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC', 'TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC', 'AGCTCCCCGTTTTC,AGCTCCCCGTTTTC']

Counter(my_list)
```

This gives output here

```
Counter({'TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC,TTATGCTAAGTATC': 2, 'AGCTCCCCGTTTTC,AGCTCCCCGTTTTC': 1})
```

Comment: This looks much more like what I think the OP is trying to do than the currently highest rank answer.